# JSON format error when trying to generate an Android apk using Sencha 2.3.1

Tags: android, json, extjs, tizen

I'm developing a Tizen application and I'm trying to run it on my Android device.
I saw that Sencha Touch is a way to build applications to run on other plataforms, like Android. So, I installed it and I'm trying to generate an apk file to test.
Although, I'm having problems with this part. My JSON file can't be read and I'm getting this exception.
Here's my config file:

```
"applicationName":"Teste",
"applicationId":"com.teste.teste",
"bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",
"versionString":"1.0",
"versionCode":"1",
"icon": {
    "36":"resources/icons/Icon_Android36.png",
    "48":"resources/icons/Icon_Android48.png",
    "72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
    "96":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png",
},
"inputPath":"C:\Users\User\ambiente_tizen\tizen\build",
"outputPath":"C:\Users\User\Desktop\apks",
"configuration":"Debug",
"platform":"Android",
"deviceType":"Universal",
"certificatePath":"C:\Users\User\.android",
"certificateAlias":"androiddebugkey",
"certificatePassword":"android",
"provisionProfile":"",
"URLScheme":"",
"notificationConfiguration":"",
"sdkPath":"C:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917/sdk",
"androidAPILevel":"18",
"permissions":[
    "INTERNET",
    "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
    "CAMERA",
    "VIBRATE",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "CALL_PHONE"
],
"orientations": [
    "portrait",
    "landscapeLeft",
    "landscapeRight",
    "portraitUpsideDown"
]
```

I'm using the command: sencha app package run androididpackager.json, but until now, without success, on my Windows 7 64bits.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Opening and closing JSON brackets {} ?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've already checked this. My JSON has both brackets. Any other suggestions?